# audio to real numbers

Tags: java, audio

I am able to convert my audio into byte values.

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException;


public class Audio_to_bytes {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        File WAV_FILE = new File("/home/cybersecurity/Desktop/scream2.wav");
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        AudioInputStream in = null;
        try {
            in = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(WAV_FILE);
        } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        int read, i;
        byte[] buff = new byte[1024];
        while ((read = in.read(buff)) > 0) {
            out.write(buff, 0, read);
        }
        out.flush();
        byte[] audioBytes = out.toByteArray();


    }
}
```

I want to identify audios which contains scream in them.For that i need to convert my audio into real  numbers so that i can apply fft on it.Can anyone help me how this can be done

Comment: Can't you create a `float[]` and cast each byte in `audioBytes` to float?

Comment: If i do so it will be simply like 127 is converted to 127.0.
I want to directly convert it into float values

Comment: So you assume each 4 bytes in the buffer represent a float value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with this code snippet and tested it. I hope it helps. I am allocating 4 floats (as bytes) I previously created and converted to bytes. Then I use the NIO FloatBuffer View of a ByteBuffer so NIO automatically returns 4 bytes as a float number without further treatment.

```
    ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(4*4);
    bb.put(new byte[]{64,-112,0,0,66,-10, 22,-68, 66,9, 73, -43, 63,-114, 56, -38});
    bb.rewind();
    FloatBuffer floatBuffer = bb.asFloatBuffer();


    for(int i = 0; i < 4;i++){
        System.out.println(floatBuffer.get());
    }
```

Comment: This is working fine but for few audio files some values are NaN.

Comment: Maybe those files are corrupted and the bytes contained can't form a valid float number. That kind of file treatment has to be done on your program like, if you get NaN replace it with the average value between the previous and the next value, or just try to get a better file :p

Comment: And also, if it was useful and worked for you, please validate the answer :)